# R TryCatch not working with lapply

Tags: r

I am trying to apply a function to a list of files using `lapply` (I make a few operations on a data frame and then write plots). The problem is that it seems that if the function raises an error for a file

> (a calculation on the data frame cannot be made)

, the iteration stops.

I used tryCatch both within the function

```
ee = function(i){return(tryCatch(..., error=function(e) NULL))}
```

and in `lapply`

```
lapply(list.files(path), tryCatch(ee, error=function(e) NULL)))
```

but in either case, I continue to get the error detected and the iteration stopped. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try something like `lapply(list.files(path), function(x) { ee(x) })` ?

Comment: `lapply`'s second parameter must be passed a function. You are passing a function call.

Comment: ee is a function, not a function call.

Comment: `tryCatch(ee, error=function(e) NULL)` is a function call.

Comment: Interestingly, I do not get any error message in that respect, and "ee" is still partly evaluated. In any case, the first example does not work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your first example should work in principle, but don't understand what you are doing with the ellipses there.

Here is a simple minimal example:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  if (x == 6) stop("no 6 for you")
  x
}

l <- list(1, 5, 6, 10)

lapply(l, foo)
# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : no 6 for you 

bar <- function(x) tryCatch(foo(x), error = function(e) e)
lapply(l, bar)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 5
#
#[[3]]
#<simpleError in foo(x): no 6 for you>
#  
#[[4]]
#[1] 10

baz <- function(x) tryCatch({
  if (x == 6) stop("no 6 for you")
  x
}, error = function(e) e)
lapply(l, baz)
#also works
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Do you know why if I put tryCatch inside ee it does not work? When the error occurs inside ee, the function(e) should be evaluated and so prevent the error. I have to add that my function saves the plot it creates but they get distorted. This does not happen if I perform the for-loop on the files externally, via another programming language.

Comment: I have found the solution to correct save the image. I have to adjust my window in Rstudio...but can I specify the saved picture size in the script?

Comment: This helped me a lot, why didn't it get an upvote? (I fixed that)

Answer (score 0):

define ee like that

```
ee <- function (i) {
  return(tryCatch(....., error=function(e) NULL))
}
```

and then call lapply that way

```
lapply(list.files(path), ee)
```

Comment: This is what I wrote